# Mysql REGEX Matching query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, regex

What is the correct query to match string variable with MySQL field?
For example:

```
$var_surname = $_POST['surname'];
$var_surname = strtolower($var_surname);

SELECT surname FROM tblname WHERE LOWER(surname) REGEX $var_surname
..........
..........

if($check > 0)
{
    Surname already exists
} 
else 
{
    Successful
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I hope you're sanitizing `$var_surname` before inserting it into the SQL like that!

Comment: In fact, even if you are sanitizing it, running a user-supplied regex on your database server is asking for a DoS attack. It also means you have to sanitize it for SQL while not affecting the regex. Never simply trust what you get from $_POST, it's trivial to view and edit that from client-side.

Comment: @Justin I wish I could upvote your comments 100x.

Answer (score 1):

`REGEX` isn't a valid MySQL operator, it's [`REGEXP`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html):

```
SELECT surname FROM tblname WHERE LOWER(surname) REGEXP '$var_surname';
```

However, `REGEXP` looks like it's overkill in this case -- the [`LIKE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html) operator or a simple equality test should work fine:

```
SELECT surname FROM tblname WHERE LOWER(surname) LIKE '$var_surname';
```

Or:

```
SELECT surname FROM tblname WHERE LOWER(surname) = '$var_surname';
```

And **please** sanitize `$var_surname` before using it in your query -- use [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) or [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php)!

Comment: Tried LIKE and = Not validating.Remember I am working with strings.

Comment: @Frank How does `$var_surname` get created?

Comment: @Frank: LIKE and = should both work on MySQL string values. Have you tried validating `SELECT surname FROM tblname WHERE LOWER(surname) = 'test';` on your database server? The validation failure probably isn't coming from where you think it is.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand, why are you using REGEX (should be [REGEXP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html) by the way) ? Just do

```
"SELECT surname FROM tblname WHERE LOWER(surname) = '$var_surname'"
```